# How to delete list items from list in python

Tags: python, arraylist, data-science

I have a list with strings and super script characters(as power).
I need to concatenate scripted values with strings.
But according to my coding part It repeating same value twice.
I have no idea to remove unnecessary values from the list.

my original list -->

```
separate_units = ['N', 'm', '⁻²⁴', 'kJ', 's', '⁻¹', 'km', '⁻²¹', 'kJ', '⁻²', 'm', '⁻²']
```

result according to my coding part -->

```
result = ['N', 'm', 'm⁻²⁴', 'kJ', 's', 's⁻¹', 'km', 'km⁻²¹', 'kJ', 'kJ⁻²', 'm', 'kJ⁻²']
```

I expected result -->

```
 result = ['N', 'm⁻²⁴', 'kJ', 's⁻¹',  'km⁻²¹',  'kJ⁻²', 'm', 'kJ⁻²']
```

I tried to delete last index when concatenate two items.But It gave me an error.

-->  del (separating_units[(separate_units.index(su) - 1)])  # grab the last (index of unit) value to delete from the list.

Error coding part -->

```
def power_set_to_unit():
    result = [su if su.isalpha() else del (separating_units[(separate_units.index(su) - 1)]) (separate_units[(separate_units.index(su) - 1)] + su) for su in separate_units]
    print(result)
```

*I prefer to do this in single line coding part.*
Please help me to do this...

Comment: do not use `del` applied to the list you are filtering in list comprehensions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside the function `power_set_to_unit`, you can iterate deciding whether to start a new entry in `result`, or append to the last element if you found an exponent:

```
separate_units = ['N', 'm', '⁻²⁴', 'kJ', 's', '⁻¹', 'km', '⁻²¹', 'kJ', '⁻²', 'm', '⁻²']

def power_set_to_unit():
    result = []
    for x in separate_units:
        if x.isalpha():
            result.append(x)
        else:
            result[-1] += x
    return result

print(power_set_to_unit())
# ['N', 'm⁻²⁴', 'kJ', 's⁻¹', 'km⁻²¹', 'kJ⁻²', 'm⁻²']
```

---

PS. One-liner:

```
power_set_to_unit = lambda sep='\n': ''.join((sep+x if x.isalpha() else x) for x in separate_units).split(sep)[1:]
print(power_set_to_unit())
# ['N', 'm⁻²⁴', 'kJ', 's⁻¹', 'km⁻²¹', 'kJ⁻²', 'm⁻²']
```

The basic idea is to add a separator between characters when a exponent is not detected.

Comment: Excuse me, I already do it by some method like this sir. Bu t I need to do this in a  single line coding part.

Comment: Hi @sonny, I added a one-liner solution. Sorry for the delay, enjoy :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another oneliner using list comprehension and `zip` for a look ahead:

```py
separate_units = ['N', 'm', '⁻²⁴', 'kJ', 's', '⁻¹', 'km', '⁻²¹', 'kJ', '⁻²', 'm', '⁻²']

[a if b.isalpha() else a + b for (a,b) in zip(separate_units[:-1], separate_units[1:]) if a.isalpha()]
# should result in ['N', 'm⁻²⁴', 'kJ', 's⁻¹', 'km⁻²¹', 'kJ⁻²', 'm⁻²']
```

To answer the question in the title of your post, to delete an item in list comprehension put the filter in an `if`-condition that follows the `for`-`in` block. For example, to get rid of non-alphabetic strings in a string list `string_list` just use

```py
[x for x in string_list if x.isalpha()]
```